# No data is displayed with ExtJS and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have a problem with `ExtJS` and `c#` does not show me any data only header, I just want to show the records of my sql table, but I could not, my backend works fine and if it returns the records of my BD, the problem is that it does not they are binding, reason why I believe that my JS file is bad and did not find the error so that the registers are shown.

[image]

data that return GetCustomer method

[image]
**app.js:**

```js
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.panel.*',
    'Ext.util.*'
]);

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            // Load data at once
            autoLoad: true,
            // Override default http proxy settings
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
                startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
                limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
                noCache: false, //to remove param "_dc"
                // Call web service method using GET syntax
                url: 'GetCustomers',
                // Ask for Json response
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }),
            // Root variable
            root: 'data',
            // Record identifier
            id: 'EmpleadoId',
            //reader:Jreader,
            // Fields declaration
            fields: ['EmpleadoId', 'NombreEmpleado', 'DirectorId'],
        });

        var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            // Set store
            store: myStore,
            // Columns definition
            columns: [{
                dataIndex: 'EmpleadoId',
                header: 'Empleado Id'
            }, {
                dataIndex: 'NombreEmpleado',
                header: 'Nombre Empleado'
            }, {
                dataIndex: 'DirectorId',
                header: 'Director Id'
            }],
            // Render grid to dom element with id set to panel
            renderTo: 'whitespace',
            width: 422,
            height: 300
        });
    }
});
```

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/charts-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="whitespace"></div>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetCustomers()
{    
    List<Empleados> lstPersona = new List<Empleados>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=PC;Database=TestPersona;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpleadoId,NombreEmpleado,DirectorId FROM Empleados", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Empleados emp = new Empleados();
        emp.EmpleadoId = Convert.ToInt16(dr["EmpleadoId"]);
        emp.NombreEmpleado = dr["NombreEmpleado"].ToString();
        emp.DirectorId = Convert.ToInt16(dr["DirectorId"]);


        lstPersona.Add(emp);
    }

    con.Close();
    JsonResult res = Json(new { data = lstPersona }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please break your question apart.  First, is your data being returned?  If so, show the shape of the response data, and include it.  If your trouble is only rendering, ask that question specifically.  Try creating a codepen with sample data (as returned from your api/data call) and what isn't working.  Include a reference, as well as any relevant pieces of code in the question.

Comment: Can you show the response from your web service in Chrome’s network tab?

Comment: @Martin above I put the response from my method